# PHP - ODBC (MS-SQL) - API returns string for a decimal (,) number

Tags: php, odbc, apache2, unixodbc

We have changed from a Windows 10 (XAMPP, PHP 7.4) web server to an Ubuntu Apache2 PHP 7.4 ODBC 17 server without making any code changes.

However, when we run the same script, we receive a different response in the RestAPI.

Windows: (how we want it to be)

```
  "data": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "MSK_Version": 3.09,
            "Materialstamm": "2022-01-18 11:33:07",
            "Main_Sync": "2022-06-15 08:45:51",
            "DB_Version": "2018-10-31 16:21:09",
            "Kill_System": null,
            "Broadcast": "Neue Version verfügbar.",
            "Adressen": "2019-03-09 15:26:10",
            "Projekte": "2019-07-11 16:58:44",
            "Dokumente_Historie": 10,
            "Abfrage_Timeout": null,
            "Verbindungstimeout": 20000,
            "Abfrageintervall": 5
        }
    ],
    "success": true
}
```

Ubuntu:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "MSK_Version": "3.09",
            "Materialstamm": "2022-01-18 11:33:07",
            "Main_Sync": "2022-06-15 08:45:51",
            "DB_Version": "2018-10-31 16:21:09",
            "Kill_System": "",
            "Broadcast": "Neue Version verfügbar.",
            "Adressen": "2019-03-09 15:26:10",
            "Projekte": "2019-07-11 16:58:44",
            "Dokumente_Historie": 10,
            "Abfrage_Timeout": null,
            "Verbindungstimeout": 20000,
            "Abfrageintervall": 5
        }
    ],
    "success": true
}
```

The locale settings for PHP are set to "de_DE.utf-8".

We have set all locale settings from ubuntu to "de_DE.utf-8".
Also have we try to run the same on Debian with ODBC18 - PHP8.0 with the same result.

On all XAMPP (Windows) servers it runs correctly.

**EDIT**

CODE:

API CLASS

```
<?php

class API {
    public static function sendError( $text, $responseCode = 500 ) {
        API::sendResponse( false, array(
            "error" => $text
        ), $responseCode );
    }

    public static function sendResponse( $success, $data, $responseCode = 0 ) {
        if( !$responseCode ) {
            $responseCode = $success ? 200 : 500;
        }
        http_response_code( $responseCode );
        $data["success"] = $success;
        echo my_json_encode( $data );
        exit();
    }

    //  read one record from the result
    public static function readRecord( $result, $pSet ) {
        $data = $result->fetchAssoc();
        if( !$data ) {
            return null;
        }
        foreach( array_keys( $data ) as $f ) {
            if( IsBinaryType( $pSet->getFieldType( $f ) ) ) {
                $data[ $f ] = base64_encode( $data[ $f ] );
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }

    //  read result into array of records
    public static function readResult( $result, $pSet, $recordLimit = 0 ) {
        $ret = array();
        while( ( !$recordLimit || count( $ret ) < $recordLimit  ) && ( $data = API::readRecord( $result, $pSet ) ) ) {
            $ret[] = $data;
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    public static function login() {
        if( !Security::hasLogin() ) {
            return true;
        }
        $authType = GetGlobalData("restAuth");
        if( $authType == REST_BASIC ) {
            //  Authorization: Basic <base64_encode(username:password)>
            $username = "";
            $password = "";
                        $username = $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"];
            $password = $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"];
            if( !$username ) {
                $loginHeader = getHttpHeader('Authorization') . "";
                if( substr( $loginHeader, 0, 6 ) !== 'Basic ' ) {
                    header( 'WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="REST API"');
                    return false;
                }
                $token = base64_decode( substr( $loginHeader, 6) );
                $colonPos = strpos( $token, ':' );
                if( $colonPos === false ) {
                    return false;
                }
                $username = substr( $token, 0, $colonPos );
                $password = substr( $token, $colonPos + 1 );
            }
            return Security::login( $username, $password, false, true );
        }
        
        if ( $authType == REST_APIKEY ) {
            $APIkey = "";
            if( isset( $_SERVER["HTTP_X_AUTH_TOKEN"] ) )
                $APIkey = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_AUTH_TOKEN"];
            else if( isset( $_GET["apikey"] ) )
                $APIkey = $_GET["apikey"];
            else if( isset( $_POST["apikey"] ) )
                $APIkey = $_POST["apikey"];
            
            if( !strlen( $APIkey ) )
                return false;
            
            if( Security::hardcodedLogin() ) {
                if( GetGlobalData("APIkey", "") == $APIkey ) {
                    Security::createHardcodedSession();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            
            $dataSource = getLoginDataSource();
            
            $dc = new DsCommand();
            $dc->filter = DataCondition::FieldEquals( GetGlobalData("APIkeyField"), $APIkey );
            $rs = $dataSource->getSingle( $dc );
            if( !$rs )
                return false;
            
            $loginSet = ProjectSettings::getForLogin();
            $cipherer = RunnerCipherer::getForLogin( $loginSet );
            $userData = $cipherer->DecryptFetchedArray( $rs->fetchAssoc() );
            
            return Security::login( $userData[ Security::usernameField() ], $userData[ Security::passwordField() ], true, true );
        }       
        
        return false;
    }

    public static function keysFromRequest( $pSet ) {
        $keys = array();
        foreach( $pSet->getTableKeys() as $i => $k ) {
            $keys[ $k ] = postvalue( "editid" . ( $i + 1 ) );
        }
        return $keys;
    }

    public static function valuesFromRequest( $pSet ) {
        $values = array();
        foreach( $pSet->getFieldsList() as $f ) {
            if( isset( $_POST[ $f ] ) ) {
                $values[ $f ] = $_POST[ $f ];
                if( IsBinaryType( $pSet->getFieldType( $f ) ) ) {
                    $values[ $f ] = base64_decode( $values[ $f ] );
                }
            }
            
        }
        return $values;
    }
}
?>
```

API

```
<?php
@ini_set("display_errors","1");
$restApiCall = true;

require_once("../include/dbcommon.php");
add_nocache_headers();

require_once(getabspath( "api/api.php"));

if( !GetGlobalData("restCreate") ) {
    return;
}

header("Content-Type: application/json");

if( !API::login() ) {
    API::sendError( 'Access denied', 401 );
}

//  dont' remember anything
session_destroy();

$table = findTable( postvalue("table") );
if( !$table ) {
    API::sendError( 'Unknown table name', 403 );
}

$pSet = new ProjectSettings( $table );
$eventsObject = &getEventObject( $table );
$cipherer = new RunnerCipherer( $table, $pSet );

$action = postvalue("action");

if( $action === "list" ) {
    if( !$pSet->pageTypeAvailable("list") ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not supported" );
    }
    if( !Security::userCan( "S", $table ) ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not allowed" );
    }
    $dataSource = getDataSource( $table, $pSet );
    $srchObj = SearchClause::getSearchObject( $table );

    $dc = new DsCommand();
    $dc->filter = DataCondition::_And( array(
        Security::SelectCondition( "S", $pSet ),
        $srchObj->getSearchDataCondition()
    ));

    $order = postvalue("orderby");
    if( $order ) {
        $orderFields = explode( ";", $order );
        $projectFields = $pSet->getFieldsList();
        $dc->order[] = array();

        foreach( $orderFields as $f ) {
            $dir = substr( $f, 0, 1 ) == "d" ? "desc": "asc";
            $field = trim( substr( $f, 1 ) );
            if( in_array( $field, $projectFields ) ) {
                $dc->order[] = array("column" => $field, "dir" => $dir);
            }
        }
    }

    if( postvalue( "skip" ) ) {
        $dc->startRecord = (int)postvalue( "skip" );
    }
    if( postvalue( "records" ) ) {
        $dc->reccount = (int)postvalue( "records" );
    } else {
        $dc->reccount = 200;
    }
    $rs = $dataSource->getList( $dc );
    if( !$rs ) {
        API::sendError( $dataSource->lastError() );
    }
    $data = API::readResult( $rs, $pSet, $dc->reccount );
    $fields = postvalue("fields");
    if($fields){
        $arrFields = explode(",",$fields);
        foreach($data as $dkey=>$row){
            foreach($row as $key=>$field){
                if(!in_array($key,$arrFields))
                    unset($data[$dkey][$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    API::sendResponse( true, array("data" => $data ) );
}

if( $action === "view" ) {
    if( !$pSet->pageTypeAvailable("view") ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not supported" );
    }
    if( !Security::userCan( "S", $table ) ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not allowed" );
    }
    $dataSource = getDataSource( $table, $pSet );
    $dc = new DsCommand();
    $dc->keys = API::keysFromRequest( $pSet );
    $dc->filter = Security::SelectCondition( "S", $pSet );
    $rs = $dataSource->getSingle( $dc );
    if( !$rs ) {
        API::sendError( $dataSource->lastError() );
    }
    API::sendResponse( true, array("data" => API::readRecord( $rs, $pSet ) ) );
}

if( $action === "update" ) {
    if( !$pSet->pageTypeAvailable("edit") ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not supported" );
    }
    if( !Security::userCan( "E", $table ) ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not allowed" );
    }

    $dataSource = getDataSource( $table, $pSet );
    $dc = new DsCommand();
    $dc->keys = API::keysFromRequest( $pSet );
    $dc->filter = Security::SelectCondition( "S", $pSet );
    $rs = $dataSource->getSingle( $dc );
    $data = $rs->fetchAssoc();
    if(!$data){
        echo "false";
        exit();
    }

    $dataSource = getDataSource( $table, $pSet );

    $oldKeys = API::keysFromRequest( $pSet );
    $newRecordData = API::valuesFromRequest( $pSet );

    $oldRecordData = null;
    if( $eventsObject->exists("BeforeEdit") || $eventsObject->exists("AfterEdit") ) {
        $dc = new DsCommand();
        $dc->filter = Security::SelectCondition( "E", $pSet );
        $dc->keys = $oldKeys;
        $fetchedArray = $dataSource->getSingle( $dc )->fetchAssoc();
        $oldRecordData = $cipherer->DecryptFetchedArray( $fetchedArray );
    }

    if( $eventsObject->exists("BeforeEdit") ) {
        $usermessage = "";
        $keyWhereClause = KeyWhere( $oldKeys, $table );
        $pageObj = null;

        $beforeEdit = $eventsObject->BeforeEdit( $newRecordData,
            $keyWhereClause,
            $oldRecordData,
            $oldKeys,
            $usermessage,
            false,
            $pageObj );

        if( !$beforeEdit ) {
            API::sendResponse( false, array( "success" => false, "error" => $usermessage ) );
        }
    }

    $dc = new DsCommand();
    $dc->keys = $oldKeys;
    $dc->filter = Security::SelectCondition( "E", $pSet );
    $dc->values = $newRecordData;
    $ret = $dataSource->updateSingle( $dc );

    if( $ret && $eventsObject->exists("AfterEdit") ) {
        $keys = $oldKeys;
        foreach( $newRecordData as $f => $v ) {
            if( isset( $keys[ $f ] ) ) {
                $keys[ $f ] = $v;
            }
        }

        $keyWhereClause = KeyWhere( $keys, $table );
        $pageObj = null;

        $eventsObject->AfterEdit( $newRecordData,
            $keyWhereClause,
            $oldRecordData,
            $keys,
            false,
            $pageObj );
    }

    if( $ret ) {
        API::sendResponse( true, array( "success" => true ) );
    } else {
        API::sendResponse( false, array( "success" => false, "error" => $dataSource->lastError() ) );
    }
    API::sendResponse( $ret["success"], $ret );
}

if( $action === "insert" ) {
    if( !$pSet->pageTypeAvailable("add") ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not supported" );
    }

    if( !Security::userCan( "A", $table ) ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not allowed" );
    }

    $newRecordData = API::valuesFromRequest( $pSet );

    if( $eventsObject->exists("BeforeAdd") ) {
        $usermessage = "";
        $pageObj = null;
        if( !$eventsObject->BeforeAdd( $newRecordData, $usermessage, false, $pageObj ) ) {
            API::sendResponse( false, array( "success" => false, "error" => $usermessage ) );
        }
    }

    $dataSource = getDataSource( $table, $pSet );
    $dc = new DsCommand();
    $dc->values = $newRecordData;
    $ret = $dataSource->insertSingle( $dc );
    
    if( $ret && $eventsObject->exists("AfterAdd") ) {
        $pageObj = null;
        $newRecordData = $ret;
        $keys = array();
        foreach( $pSet->getTableKeys() as $kf ) {
            $keys[ $kf ] = $newRecordData[ $kf ];
        }

        $eventsObject->AfterAdd( $newRecordData, $keys, false, $pageObj );
    }
    if( $ret !== false ) {
        $k = $pSet->getTableKeys();
        API::sendResponse( true, array( "success" => true, $k[0] => $ret[$k[0]] ) );
    } else {
        API::sendResponse( false, array( "success" => false, "error" => $dataSource->lastError() ) );
    }
}

if( $action === "delete" ) {
    if( !$pSet->pageTypeAvailable("list") ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not supported" );
    }
    if( !Security::userCan( "D", $table ) ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not allowed" );
    }

    $dataSource = getDataSource( $table, $pSet );
    $dc = new DsCommand();
    $dc->keys = API::keysFromRequest( $pSet );
    $dc->filter = Security::SelectCondition( "S", $pSet );
    $rs = $dataSource->getSingle( $dc );
    $data = $rs->fetchAssoc();
    if(!$data){
        echo "false";
        exit();
    }

    $dataSource = getDataSource( $table, $pSet );
    $dc = new DsCommand();
    $dc->keys = API::keysFromRequest( $pSet );
    $dc->filter = Security::SelectCondition( "D", $pSet );

    $whereClause = "";
    $deletedValues = array();
    if( $eventsObject->exists("BeforeDelete") || $eventsObject->exists("AfterDelete") ) {
        $deletedResult = $dataSource->getSingle( $dc );
        if( $deletedResult )
            $deletedValues = $cipherer->DecryptFetchedArray( $deletedResult->fetchAssoc() );

        $whereClause = KeyWhere( $dc->keys, $table );
    }

    if( $eventsObject->exists("BeforeDelete") ) {
        $userMessage = "";
        $pageObj = null;
        if( !$eventsObject->BeforeDelete( $whereClause, $deletedValues, $userMessage, $pageObj ) ) {
            API::sendResponse( false, array( "success" => false, "error" => $userMessage ) );
        }
    }

    $ret = $dataSource->deleteSingle( $dc );

    if( $ret && $eventsObject->exists("AfterDelete") ) {
        $userMessage = "";
        $pageObj = null;
        $eventsObject->AfterDelete( $whereClause, $deletedValues, $userMessage, $pageObj );
    }

    if( $ret ) {
        API::sendResponse( true, array( "success" => true ) );
    } else {
        API::sendResponse( false, array( "success" => false, "error" => $dataSource->lastError() ) );
    }
}

API::sendError( "unknown operation" );

?>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue. See also [ask]. We cannot see the source data, nor can we see the code which was used to generate the output. Therefore it's impossible to suggest what to fix. I doubt locale has anything to do with it, it seems to be a data type issue. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: Do some research into the ODBC driver you're using. I know that the driver for MySQL tends to return all values (including ints/decimals) as strings with certain drivers on certain OS's. Check if it's a similar thing here.

Answer (score 0):

API CLASS

```
<?php

class API {
    public static function sendError( $text, $responseCode = 500 ) {
        API::sendResponse( false, array(
            "error" => $text
        ), $responseCode );
    }

    public static function sendResponse( $success, $data, $responseCode = 0 ) {
        if( !$responseCode ) {
            $responseCode = $success ? 200 : 500;
        }
        http_response_code( $responseCode );
        $data["success"] = $success;
        echo my_json_encode( $data );
        exit();
    }

    //  read one record from the result
    public static function readRecord( $result, $pSet ) {
        $data = $result->fetchAssoc();
        if( !$data ) {
            return null;
        }
        foreach( array_keys( $data ) as $f ) {
            if( IsBinaryType( $pSet->getFieldType( $f ) ) ) {
                $data[ $f ] = base64_encode( $data[ $f ] );
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }

    //  read result into array of records
    public static function readResult( $result, $pSet, $recordLimit = 0 ) {
        $ret = array();
        while( ( !$recordLimit || count( $ret ) < $recordLimit  ) && ( $data = API::readRecord( $result, $pSet ) ) ) {
            $ret[] = $data;
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    public static function login() {
        if( !Security::hasLogin() ) {
            return true;
        }
        $authType = GetGlobalData("restAuth");
        if( $authType == REST_BASIC ) {
            //  Authorization: Basic <base64_encode(username:password)>
            $username = "";
            $password = "";
                        $username = $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"];
            $password = $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"];
            if( !$username ) {
                $loginHeader = getHttpHeader('Authorization') . "";
                if( substr( $loginHeader, 0, 6 ) !== 'Basic ' ) {
                    header( 'WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="REST API"');
                    return false;
                }
                $token = base64_decode( substr( $loginHeader, 6) );
                $colonPos = strpos( $token, ':' );
                if( $colonPos === false ) {
                    return false;
                }
                $username = substr( $token, 0, $colonPos );
                $password = substr( $token, $colonPos + 1 );
            }
            return Security::login( $username, $password, false, true );
        }
        
        if ( $authType == REST_APIKEY ) {
            $APIkey = "";
            if( isset( $_SERVER["HTTP_X_AUTH_TOKEN"] ) )
                $APIkey = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_AUTH_TOKEN"];
            else if( isset( $_GET["apikey"] ) )
                $APIkey = $_GET["apikey"];
            else if( isset( $_POST["apikey"] ) )
                $APIkey = $_POST["apikey"];
            
            if( !strlen( $APIkey ) )
                return false;
            
            if( Security::hardcodedLogin() ) {
                if( GetGlobalData("APIkey", "") == $APIkey ) {
                    Security::createHardcodedSession();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            
            $dataSource = getLoginDataSource();
            
            $dc = new DsCommand();
            $dc->filter = DataCondition::FieldEquals( GetGlobalData("APIkeyField"), $APIkey );
            $rs = $dataSource->getSingle( $dc );
            if( !$rs )
                return false;
            
            $loginSet = ProjectSettings::getForLogin();
            $cipherer = RunnerCipherer::getForLogin( $loginSet );
            $userData = $cipherer->DecryptFetchedArray( $rs->fetchAssoc() );
            
            return Security::login( $userData[ Security::usernameField() ], $userData[ Security::passwordField() ], true, true );
        }       
        
        return false;
    }

    public static function keysFromRequest( $pSet ) {
        $keys = array();
        foreach( $pSet->getTableKeys() as $i => $k ) {
            $keys[ $k ] = postvalue( "editid" . ( $i + 1 ) );
        }
        return $keys;
    }

    public static function valuesFromRequest( $pSet ) {
        $values = array();
        foreach( $pSet->getFieldsList() as $f ) {
            if( isset( $_POST[ $f ] ) ) {
                $values[ $f ] = $_POST[ $f ];
                if( IsBinaryType( $pSet->getFieldType( $f ) ) ) {
                    $values[ $f ] = base64_decode( $values[ $f ] );
                }
            }
            
        }
        return $values;
    }
}
?>
```

API

```
<?php
@ini_set("display_errors","1");
$restApiCall = true;

require_once("../include/dbcommon.php");
add_nocache_headers();

require_once(getabspath( "api/api.php"));

if( !GetGlobalData("restCreate") ) {
    return;
}

header("Content-Type: application/json");

if( !API::login() ) {
    API::sendError( 'Access denied', 401 );
}

//  dont' remember anything
session_destroy();

$table = findTable( postvalue("table") );
if( !$table ) {
    API::sendError( 'Unknown table name', 403 );
}

$pSet = new ProjectSettings( $table );
$eventsObject = &getEventObject( $table );
$cipherer = new RunnerCipherer( $table, $pSet );

$action = postvalue("action");

if( $action === "list" ) {
    if( !$pSet->pageTypeAvailable("list") ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not supported" );
    }
    if( !Security::userCan( "S", $table ) ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not allowed" );
    }
    $dataSource = getDataSource( $table, $pSet );
    $srchObj = SearchClause::getSearchObject( $table );

    $dc = new DsCommand();
    $dc->filter = DataCondition::_And( array(
        Security::SelectCondition( "S", $pSet ),
        $srchObj->getSearchDataCondition()
    ));

    $order = postvalue("orderby");
    if( $order ) {
        $orderFields = explode( ";", $order );
        $projectFields = $pSet->getFieldsList();
        $dc->order[] = array();

        foreach( $orderFields as $f ) {
            $dir = substr( $f, 0, 1 ) == "d" ? "desc": "asc";
            $field = trim( substr( $f, 1 ) );
            if( in_array( $field, $projectFields ) ) {
                $dc->order[] = array("column" => $field, "dir" => $dir);
            }
        }
    }

    if( postvalue( "skip" ) ) {
        $dc->startRecord = (int)postvalue( "skip" );
    }
    if( postvalue( "records" ) ) {
        $dc->reccount = (int)postvalue( "records" );
    } else {
        $dc->reccount = 200;
    }
    $rs = $dataSource->getList( $dc );
    if( !$rs ) {
        API::sendError( $dataSource->lastError() );
    }
    $data = API::readResult( $rs, $pSet, $dc->reccount );
    $fields = postvalue("fields");
    if($fields){
        $arrFields = explode(",",$fields);
        foreach($data as $dkey=>$row){
            foreach($row as $key=>$field){
                if(!in_array($key,$arrFields))
                    unset($data[$dkey][$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    API::sendResponse( true, array("data" => $data ) );
}

if( $action === "view" ) {
    if( !$pSet->pageTypeAvailable("view") ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not supported" );
    }
    if( !Security::userCan( "S", $table ) ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not allowed" );
    }
    $dataSource = getDataSource( $table, $pSet );
    $dc = new DsCommand();
    $dc->keys = API::keysFromRequest( $pSet );
    $dc->filter = Security::SelectCondition( "S", $pSet );
    $rs = $dataSource->getSingle( $dc );
    if( !$rs ) {
        API::sendError( $dataSource->lastError() );
    }
    API::sendResponse( true, array("data" => API::readRecord( $rs, $pSet ) ) );
}

if( $action === "update" ) {
    if( !$pSet->pageTypeAvailable("edit") ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not supported" );
    }
    if( !Security::userCan( "E", $table ) ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not allowed" );
    }

    $dataSource = getDataSource( $table, $pSet );
    $dc = new DsCommand();
    $dc->keys = API::keysFromRequest( $pSet );
    $dc->filter = Security::SelectCondition( "S", $pSet );
    $rs = $dataSource->getSingle( $dc );
    $data = $rs->fetchAssoc();
    if(!$data){
        echo "false";
        exit();
    }

    $dataSource = getDataSource( $table, $pSet );

    $oldKeys = API::keysFromRequest( $pSet );
    $newRecordData = API::valuesFromRequest( $pSet );

    $oldRecordData = null;
    if( $eventsObject->exists("BeforeEdit") || $eventsObject->exists("AfterEdit") ) {
        $dc = new DsCommand();
        $dc->filter = Security::SelectCondition( "E", $pSet );
        $dc->keys = $oldKeys;
        $fetchedArray = $dataSource->getSingle( $dc )->fetchAssoc();
        $oldRecordData = $cipherer->DecryptFetchedArray( $fetchedArray );
    }

    if( $eventsObject->exists("BeforeEdit") ) {
        $usermessage = "";
        $keyWhereClause = KeyWhere( $oldKeys, $table );
        $pageObj = null;

        $beforeEdit = $eventsObject->BeforeEdit( $newRecordData,
            $keyWhereClause,
            $oldRecordData,
            $oldKeys,
            $usermessage,
            false,
            $pageObj );

        if( !$beforeEdit ) {
            API::sendResponse( false, array( "success" => false, "error" => $usermessage ) );
        }
    }

    $dc = new DsCommand();
    $dc->keys = $oldKeys;
    $dc->filter = Security::SelectCondition( "E", $pSet );
    $dc->values = $newRecordData;
    $ret = $dataSource->updateSingle( $dc );

    if( $ret && $eventsObject->exists("AfterEdit") ) {
        $keys = $oldKeys;
        foreach( $newRecordData as $f => $v ) {
            if( isset( $keys[ $f ] ) ) {
                $keys[ $f ] = $v;
            }
        }

        $keyWhereClause = KeyWhere( $keys, $table );
        $pageObj = null;

        $eventsObject->AfterEdit( $newRecordData,
            $keyWhereClause,
            $oldRecordData,
            $keys,
            false,
            $pageObj );
    }

    if( $ret ) {
        API::sendResponse( true, array( "success" => true ) );
    } else {
        API::sendResponse( false, array( "success" => false, "error" => $dataSource->lastError() ) );
    }
    API::sendResponse( $ret["success"], $ret );
}

if( $action === "insert" ) {
    if( !$pSet->pageTypeAvailable("add") ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not supported" );
    }

    if( !Security::userCan( "A", $table ) ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not allowed" );
    }

    $newRecordData = API::valuesFromRequest( $pSet );

    if( $eventsObject->exists("BeforeAdd") ) {
        $usermessage = "";
        $pageObj = null;
        if( !$eventsObject->BeforeAdd( $newRecordData, $usermessage, false, $pageObj ) ) {
            API::sendResponse( false, array( "success" => false, "error" => $usermessage ) );
        }
    }

    $dataSource = getDataSource( $table, $pSet );
    $dc = new DsCommand();
    $dc->values = $newRecordData;
    $ret = $dataSource->insertSingle( $dc );
    
    if( $ret && $eventsObject->exists("AfterAdd") ) {
        $pageObj = null;
        $newRecordData = $ret;
        $keys = array();
        foreach( $pSet->getTableKeys() as $kf ) {
            $keys[ $kf ] = $newRecordData[ $kf ];
        }

        $eventsObject->AfterAdd( $newRecordData, $keys, false, $pageObj );
    }
    if( $ret !== false ) {
        $k = $pSet->getTableKeys();
        API::sendResponse( true, array( "success" => true, $k[0] => $ret[$k[0]] ) );
    } else {
        API::sendResponse( false, array( "success" => false, "error" => $dataSource->lastError() ) );
    }
}

if( $action === "delete" ) {
    if( !$pSet->pageTypeAvailable("list") ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not supported" );
    }
    if( !Security::userCan( "D", $table ) ) {
        API::sendError( "operation not allowed" );
    }

    $dataSource = getDataSource( $table, $pSet );
    $dc = new DsCommand();
    $dc->keys = API::keysFromRequest( $pSet );
    $dc->filter = Security::SelectCondition( "S", $pSet );
    $rs = $dataSource->getSingle( $dc );
    $data = $rs->fetchAssoc();
    if(!$data){
        echo "false";
        exit();
    }

    $dataSource = getDataSource( $table, $pSet );
    $dc = new DsCommand();
    $dc->keys = API::keysFromRequest( $pSet );
    $dc->filter = Security::SelectCondition( "D", $pSet );

    $whereClause = "";
    $deletedValues = array();
    if( $eventsObject->exists("BeforeDelete") || $eventsObject->exists("AfterDelete") ) {
        $deletedResult = $dataSource->getSingle( $dc );
        if( $deletedResult )
            $deletedValues = $cipherer->DecryptFetchedArray( $deletedResult->fetchAssoc() );

        $whereClause = KeyWhere( $dc->keys, $table );
    }

    if( $eventsObject->exists("BeforeDelete") ) {
        $userMessage = "";
        $pageObj = null;
        if( !$eventsObject->BeforeDelete( $whereClause, $deletedValues, $userMessage, $pageObj ) ) {
            API::sendResponse( false, array( "success" => false, "error" => $userMessage ) );
        }
    }

    $ret = $dataSource->deleteSingle( $dc );

    if( $ret && $eventsObject->exists("AfterDelete") ) {
        $userMessage = "";
        $pageObj = null;
        $eventsObject->AfterDelete( $whereClause, $deletedValues, $userMessage, $pageObj );
    }

    if( $ret ) {
        API::sendResponse( true, array( "success" => true ) );
    } else {
        API::sendResponse( false, array( "success" => false, "error" => $dataSource->lastError() ) );
    }
}

API::sendError( "unknown operation" );

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

The way it is output now, shows that it is casted as a string, not as a numeric value.

Try casting it right before the output, with `(float) $version`

PHP does not inherit by default the system locale settings. You have to either set it manually, by adding at the beginning of the script:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE");
```

Comment: I think their question is why the same code returns different data types on different systems, and not as much how to convert a string into a float. Also, your second example makes little sense. Why would they use `number_format()` if the actual format is already OK but want to get it as a float from the db instead of a string? Your example would just produce that same string again. Btw, why would the locale have anything to do with what datatypes you get from the database? A float is a float in all locales.

Comment: There is no question in the original post, just facts, that is why I wrote several approaches. The one with the number_format is indeed a wrong one, as it returns a string. Mea culpa.

Comment: Sure, but the description of the problem was pretty clear. Same code, different OS's, different datatypes in the response from the database. And again, what does locales have to do with what datatype you get from the database?

Comment: In the lower part of the post, they mention the fact that they set the locale settings in Ubuntu. My comment stated the fact that PHP may ignore that, and has it's own way to set up the locale :)

Comment: @grinch7117 yes they did...but again, how do you think the locale would be affecting the reported problem? Locale does not control the difference between float and string

Comment: I am pretty sure it does not control the difference between datatypes. 
The locale setting affects if a dot or a comma is used as a separator for generating  floats and doubles, and this was also mentioned in the initial commit of the question. 
I just responded to what was posted by the creator.

Comment: `The locale setting affects if a dot or a comma is used as a separator for generating floats and doubles`...that's not what they're complaining about. The problem is the difference between `"MSK_Version": 3.09,` and `"MSK_Version": "3.09",`